# Airflow task skips a day during backfill

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

This is a repost from a discussion in the Airflow repo:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/23808

I'm seeing unexpected behaviour with backfilling for a dag, using the airflow CLI. After running:

`gcloud composer environments run [company environment] --location [location] dags backfill -- --reset-dagruns -s 2022-05-05 -e 2022-05-18 minimal_skip`

I observe that 2022-05-05 is complete on the Airflow UI, but the next time it is run, i see 2022-05-07, rather than 2022-05-06 as expected.

[image: 2022-05-05]
[image: 2022-05-07]

```js
import os
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

from airflow_dag_utilities import airflow_dag_utilities as dag_utils

def main():
    dag_args = {
        # DAG
        # department-project_name-dag_description (inherit from definition)
        "dag_id": os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0],
        "schedule_interval": "0 0 * * *",
        "max_active_runs": 1,
        "dagrun_timeout": datetime.timedelta(minutes=59),
        "template_searchpath": ["/home/airflow/gcs/dags/minimal_skip/"],
        "catchup": False,  # must include because airflow default catchup is True
        # Operators
        "default_args": {
            # 'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 13, 15), (year, m,  d, hour)
            "start_date": None,  # time: UTC, uses dag_utils.suggest_start_date
            "owner": "xxxxxxx",
            "email": ["xxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com"],
            "depends_on_past": False,  # new instance will not run if past job failed
            "retries": 1,
            "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
            "email_on_failure": True,
            "email_on_retry": False,
        },
    }
    dag_args["default_args"]["start_date"] = dag_utils.suggest_start_date(
        dag_args["schedule_interval"], intervals=-2
    )  # remove automatic start_date assignment when using your own

    create_dag(dag_args)


def create_dag(dag_args):
    with airflow.DAG(**dag_args) as dag:
        """
        No logic outside of tasks(operators) or they are constantly run by scheduler
        """

        t_select_five = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id='select_five',
            configuration={
                'query': {
                    'query': "SELECT 5;",
                    'useLegacySql': False,
                },
            },
        )

        t_select_ten = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
            task_id='select_10',
            configuration={
                'query': {
                    'query': "SELECT 10",
                    'useLegacySql': False,
                },
            },
        )
        t_select_five >> t_select_ten

    globals()[dag.dag_id] = dag  # keep this


main()  # keep this
```

We see the same issue when `depends_on_past=True`

Why does Airflow have this behaviour when backfilling? Is this expected behaviour? I thought it was unintuitive especially since there is an option to go 'backwards' sequentially, why wouldn't it go 'forwards' sequentially without skipping days?

Using the Airflow UI to look at dag runs:
[image: dag runs]

Comment: Could you query in the airflow database on the dagrun table if there exists a record for `2022-05-06`?

Comment: I see the record for 2022-05-06, however, the actual timestamp for the run is after 2022-05-05 and 2022-05-07. So I suppose the edited question is, why does Airflow not complete the dates in the order of execution date?

Comment: You may want to share the data record in the dagrun table on the airflow database  for that dagrun as well.

Comment: I didn't run it on the airflow database directly but I've edited the post to include what it shows in the Airflow UI.

Comment: Can you produce the same behavior when you run the clear command prior to running the backfill one?

Comment: The clear command on all the days? I can see the behaviour for days that have never been run (i.e. before the start date)